# ¿Como hacer que un un double acepte comas y puntos como separador decimal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, double

Mi programa por pide el radio de un círculo, pero solo acepta punto como separador decimal, al ingresar coma como separador me lanza un "FormatException", como puedo solucionar esto?
La variable que uso es double

Comment: prueba con [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que quieres parsear?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `Double.parse()` como lo muestra la documentación, el hecho aquí es que debes usar el método que te permita parsear esos números como `Parse(String, NumberStyles)` que como segundo parámetro acepta un NumberStyles el cuál puedes consultar aquí su uso [NumberStyles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_), y probar con **NumberStyles.AllowThousands**, cabe mencionar que el uso de comas puede caer el un tema de regiones donde se usa coma para delimitar los miles y en otras regiones (country codes) se usa para delimitar partes decimales con US, para este caso puedes usar `Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)`

Comment: Graciaas, voy a probar...